# Adding Webelements in selenium

Tags: selenium

I need to capture values of webelements and find the sum of the elements and verify if the total is correct. Below is my code:

```
WebElement depCost = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/font"));

WebElement arrCost = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[3]/font"));

WebElement numOfPass = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]/font"));

WebElement taxes = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]/font"));

WebElement total = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/font/b"));

Float sumTotal=(((depCost + arrCost)*numOfPass)+taxes);
```

Here it is not able to add depCost and arrCost as they are webelements and '+'operation cannot be done for webelements is there an alternative to sum the values.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to get the text from the WebElement, and then parse the text to a number:

```
Float arrCost = Parse(driver.findElement(By.xpath("...")));
Float numOfPass = Parse(driver.findElement(By.xpath("...")));
Float taxes = Parse(driver.findElement(By.xpath("...")));
Float total = Parse(driver.findElement(By.xpath("...")));

Float sumTotal= ((depCost + arrCost) * numOfPass) + taxes;
```

And the function to parse a WebElement to a Float:

```
static Float Parse(WebElement element) {
  return Float.parseFloat(element.getText().trim());
}
```

Comment: I was able to fetch the other values .Its now throwing the following error for $44   : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "$44"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)

Comment: "$44" is not a number. Replace .trim() by .replaceAll("[^+-.\\d]+", "") to extract the number.